# You can not create the ActiveX component vb.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, vb.net, activexobject

I have a code to get an excel file for a directory in my web proyect and then open the file to get data and display it in my page:

```
   Imports System.Globalization
    Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
    Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

try

  Dim oExcel As Application = CType(CreateObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
            'm_Excel = CType(CreateObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
            Dim ruta As String = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/excel/excel1.xlsx")

            Dim oBook As Workbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(ruta, , False)
            Dim oSheet As Worksheet
            oSheet = oBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            ........ and more code
 Catch ex As Exception
Throw ex
     End Try
  End Sub
```

When I execute it in local it works fine, but when I added the proyect for example to an IIS in my local pc I get this error message:

```
You can not create the ActiveX component
```

I tried with many things but I can´t get the solution yet. :-(
Someone can know how to fix it?
I would greatly appreciate your help

Comment: Perhaps you should check what that code does - you are trying to open Excel itself (which is almost certainly *NOT* installed on the server) using COM instead of Office Interop. There are a lot of ways to read Excel files without Excel, although the easiest is to use the Open XML SDK or a library like EPPlus to read `xlsx` files.

Comment: thanks for your response, I keep looking for other options